# lista de objetos como ordenarla por numero y por fecha

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo una lista de objetos en javascript con la siguiente forma:

```
const data = [
    {
        data1:
        {
            title: 'Scaling 100k users',
            upvotes: 72,
            date: '2019-01-21'
        }
    },
    {
        data2:
        {
            title: 'the emu War',
            upvotes: 24,
            date: '2019-10-21'
        }
    },
    {
        data3: {
            title: 'Alphabet earnings',
            upvotes: 22,
            date: '2019-11-23'
        }
    },
    {
        data4: {
            title: 'A message to our customers',
            upvotes: 12,
            date: '2019-01-24'
        }
    },
    {
        data5: {
            title: 'Simple text editor has 15k monthly users',
            upvotes: 7,
            date: '2019-12-31'
        }
    },
    {
        data6: {
            title: 'Artificial Mountains',
            upvotes: 75,
            date: '2019-11-22'
        }
    },
    {
        data7: {
            title: 'What\'s SAP',
            upvotes: 1,
            date: '2019-11-21'
        }
    },
    {
        data8: {
            title: 'Eating glass',
            upvotes: 172,
            date: '2019-01-01'
        }
    }
]
```

qusiera saber si existe alguna manera de poder ordenarla de dos maneras

1. de mayor a menor , segun la cantidad de upvotes
2. segun la fecha mas reciente, segun la fecha

es un ejercicio que estoy haciendo y considero que dominar estas habilidades hara de mi un mejor programador, pero lo cierto es que no he encontrado la forma de hacerlo..aunque si he podido obtener los valores de los upvotes y ordenarlos

con respecto a la fecha no lo he hecho aun pero tambien creo poder encontrar una manera de ordenarla, el problema es como ordenar tambien el objeto al cual pertenecen

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

El principal problema es que en cada objeto tienes una propiedad `data#` diferente y hay que obtenerla con [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), accediendo al primer elemento (única propiedad), por ejemplo:

```
console.log(Object.keys(data[0])); // Salida: data1
```

Y ese dato es el que se usa como índice para obtener cada objeto dentro de `.sort()`

```js
const data = [
    {
        data1:
        {
            title: 'Scaling 100k users',
            upvotes: 72,
            date: '2019-01-21'
        }
    },
    {
        data2:
        {
            title: 'the emu War',
            upvotes: 24,
            date: '2019-10-21'
        }
    },
    {
        data3: {
            title: 'Alphabet earnings',
            upvotes: 22,
            date: '2019-11-23'
        }
    },
    {
        data4: {
            title: 'A message to our customers',
            upvotes: 12,
            date: '2019-01-24'
        }
    },
    {
        data5: {
            title: 'Simple text editor has 15k monthly users',
            upvotes: 7,
            date: '2019-12-31'
        }
    },
    {
        data6: {
            title: 'Artificial Mountains',
            upvotes: 75,
            date: '2019-11-22'
        }
    },
    {
        data7: {
            title: 'What\'s SAP',
            upvotes: 1,
            date: '2019-11-21'
        }
    },
    {
        data8: {
            title: 'Eating glass',
            upvotes: 172,
            date: '2019-01-01'
        }
    }
];

// Ordenar por votos descendente
let porVotos = data.sort((a, b) => {
    // Es necesario obtener la propiedad data# de cada elemento
    let aVotes = a[Object.keys(a)[0]].upvotes;
    let bVotes = b[Object.keys(b)[0]].upvotes;
    return bVotes - aVotes;
});
console.log(porVotos);


// Ordenar por fecha
let porFecha = data.sort((a, b) => {
    // Es necesario obtener la propiedad data# de cada elemento
    let aDate = a[Object.keys(a)[0]].date;
    let bDate = b[Object.keys(b)[0]].date;
    // Comparar como cadena
    return aDate.localeCompare(bDate);
});

console.log(porFecha);
```

Comment: Realmente no funciona... ordena, pero no se que ordena. Por ejemplo el de upvotes, ordena algo, no se que, no da error. Pero los upvotes no tienen sentido alguno.

Comment: @Excorpion, cierto, no había revisado toda la salida y por eso no me di cuenta, también se requiere acceder a la propiedad `data#`. Ya esta corregido, gracias por la observación.

Comment: Siempre para apoyarnos @Triby ;)

Comment: @Triby voy a probarlo y en un rato te cuento. Gracias..

Comment: a la perfeccion...nunca hubiera visto venir la creacion de dos nuevas variables dentro del sort() increible..gracias

Comment: Me alegra que te sirviera, de hecho, la creación de variables es opcional, pero lo dejé así para hacerlo más legible que esto: `a[Object.keys(a)[0]].date.localCompare(b[Object.keys(b)[0]].date)`. No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada, así otros usuarios con problemas similares sabrán que esto puede ser útil.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes aplicar la función `sort` para ordenarlos como quieras.
Te dejo un ejemplo de su uso en particular. (usé tus upvotes en este caso).

Link para información -> https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```js
const data = [{
    upvotes: 72
  }, {
    upvotes: 24
  }, {
    upvotes: 22
  },
  {
    upvotes: 12
  },
  {
    upvotes: 7
  }, {
    upvotes: 75
  }, {
    upvotes: 1
  }, {
    upvotes: 172
  }
]

data.sort((a, b) => (a.upvotes > b.upvotes) ? 1 : -1)

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Agrego el como ordenar por fecha -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837454/sort-array-of-objects-by-single-key-with-date-value

Comment: gracias excorpion por la prontitud con que me has respondido. te comento que si he leido sobre el sort() sin embargo, dejame probar tu respuesta y ahora vuelvo. Hasta ahora no he podido lograr ordenar un objeto entero, como en el caso de ejemplo

Comment: Creo que solo me falta lo mismo que a ti, ordenar por el objeto mismo.

Comment: creo que esto no debe ser un problema nuevo, seguro que hay alguna forma de hacerlo que estamos pasando por alto

Comment: Se me ocurre primero rescatar los datos a comparar antes de compararlos.

Comment: te comento qu ela pagina que me compartiste esta muy buena hay varias ideas a desarrollar...de ahi estoy leyendome esto ahora que puede resultar https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy